# How to have these child divs aligned to the bottom of their relatively positioned parent?

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px none;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.wrapper {
 position:relative;
 white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.item {
 /*position:absolute;*/
 display:inline-block;
 width:25%;
 height:25vw;
}


.item1 {
 background-color:wheat;
}.item2 {
 background-color:pink;
}.item3 {
 background-color:beige;
}.item4 {
 background-color:gainsboro;
}.item5 {
 background-color:coral;
}


.previous-arrow, .next-arrow {
 width:30px;
 height:50%;
 top:50%;
 position:absolute;
 opacity:0.7;
 color:transparent;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 margin-top: -30px;
 
 display:none;
}

.previous-arrow {
 background-image:url(a2.png);
 left:0px;
}

.next-arrow {
 background-image:url(b2.png);
 right:0px;
}

.previous-arrow, .next-arrow {
 opacity:1;
}

body {
 /*background-color:black;*/
}

/****************************************************************************************************************/

.name-nic-container {
 position:absolute;
 left:10%;
 bottom:10%;
 width:90%;
}

.name {
 font-size: 171.579%;
 color: black;
}

.nic {
 font-size: 114.737%;
 color: black;
 font-weight:100;
 display:block;
 line-height:0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><!--
  --><a class="previous-arrow" href="">&lt;</a><!--
        --><a id="1" class="item item1 wheat"><!--
              --><span class="name-nic-container"><!--
                --><span class="name">Amy</span><!--
                --><span class="nic">234</span><!--
              --></span><!--
          --></a><!--
  --><a id="2" class="item item2 pink"><!--
              --><span class="name-nic-container"><!--
                --><span class="name">Bob</span><!--
                --><span class="nic">344</span><!--
              --></span><!--
          --></a><!--
  --><a id="3" class="item item3 beige"><!--
              --><span class="name-nic-container"><!--
                --><span class="name">Jazz</span><!--
                --><span class="nic">345</span><!--
              --></span><!--
          --></a><!--
  --><a id="4" class="item item4 gainsboro"><!--
              --><span class="name-nic-container"><!--
                --><span class="name">Zee</span><!--
                --><span class="nic">675</span><!--
              --></span><!--
          --></a><!--
  --><a id="5" class="item item5 coral"><!--
              --><span class="name-nic-container"><!--
                --><span class="name">Ana</span><!--
                --><span class="nic">453</span><!--
              --></span><!--
          --></a><!--
  --><a class="next-arrow" href="">&gt;</a>
  
 </div>
```

[**JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/)

In this SSCCE, I want `.name` and `.nic` get bottom aligned inside `.name-nic-container`. But the result is all the `.name`s and `.nic`s smudged over each other. I gave `.name-nice-container` a `width:90%` and expected it to get 90% of its parent `.item`, but it seems to have a way longer width.

I figured that this is probably due to `position:absolute` on `.name-nic-container` (because absolutely positioned elements are rendered out of flow). So what I tried to do was to give it `position:relative`. The result was [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/1/) which was better, except that the `.name` and `.nic` were not aligned to the bottom of their parent. `bottom:10%` on `.name-nic-container` rather seemed to give it a bottom offset *compared to its current position*, which I figured was probably the normal behavior in relative position.

I gave it a negative bottom offset `bottom: -50%`, which resulted in [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/5/), and it *only seems* correct, because in the real program, the text printed in `.name` and `.nic` comes dynamically, and what if it is long enough to span more than one lines? The height of `.name` (in case the text to be printed in `.name` is very long) will expand downwards. But what I need is that it should be aligned to the bottom - i.e. if the text is longer, the `span` should expand upwards (I hope I am saying it clearly).

Then I tried to give `display:table` to `.name-nic-container` and `display:table-row` to each of `.name` and `.nic`, which resulted in [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/3/). And giving `.name-nic-container` a `height:100%` resulted in [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/4/).

**So what should I do to have `.name` and `.nic` aligned to the bottom of `.name-nic-container`** and have a small left and bottom offset (like 10px or 10% etc. - I think padding will do that)**?**

Comment: Did you try `.item { position: relative; }`? http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/6/

Comment: @makshh (1) Thanks, that solves my problem, but there is one problem: If the name is bigger, it won't wrap to the next line. It will instead be hidden: [http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/qrvxtxfd/7/) (2) If you can post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the elements' parents that are positioned as `absolute`.

Elements with `absolute` positioning will position themselves relatively to the nearest parent with a `position` property. Since `.item` has no explicit positioning rule, your `.name-nic-container` element was positioning itself relative to your `body` element. You can read more about positioning [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

```
.item {
  position: relative;
}
```

The reason your `.name` isn't wrapping is because of the code you have below, remove that and it will wrap.

```
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```